# How to save each named tibble in a list, as a separate tibble or dataframe in one run

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tibble

This question is related to this [How to loop over the columns in a dataframe, apply spread, and create a new dataframe in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73436305/how-to-loop-over-the-columns-in-a-dataframe-apply-spread-and-create-a-new-data)

I have a list with 3 tibbles:

```
$Peter
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date       Peter   Ben  Mary
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-03-30   0.4  NA    NA  
2 2020-10-14  NA     0.6  NA  
3 2020-12-06  NA    NA     0.7

$Ben
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date       Peter   Ben  Mary
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-03-30   0.5  NA    NA  
2 2020-10-14  NA     0.4  NA  
3 2020-12-06  NA    NA     0.2

$Mary
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date       Peter   Ben  Mary
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-03-30   0.2  NA    NA  
2 2020-10-14  NA     0.1  NA  
3 2020-12-06  NA    NA     0.9

mylistdf <- list(Peter = structure(list(date = c("2020-03-30", "2020-10-14", 
"2020-12-06"), Peter = c(0.4, NA, NA), Ben = c(NA, 0.6, NA), 
    Mary = c(NA, NA, 0.7)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Ben = structure(list(date = c("2020-03-30", 
"2020-10-14", "2020-12-06"), Peter = c(0.5, NA, NA), Ben = c(NA, 
0.4, NA), Mary = c(NA, NA, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Mary = structure(list(date = c("2020-03-30", 
"2020-10-14", "2020-12-06"), Peter = c(0.2, NA, NA), Ben = c(NA, 
0.1, NA), Mary = c(NA, NA, 0.9)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

**How can I save all this 3 tibbles as an own tibble in the global environment:**

Expected output would be kind of having Peter, Ben, Mary as tibbles or dataframes in the global environment.

I know we could do:

```
Peter <- mylistdf$Peter
Ben <- mylistdf$Ben
Mary <- mylistdf$Mary
```

But I whish to do it in one run with map or similar like:

```
mylistdf %>%
  .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `%=%`

```
library(collapse)
names(mylistdf) %=% mylistdf
```

-checking

```
> Peter
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  date       Peter   Ben  Mary
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-03-30   0.4  NA    NA  
2 2020-10-14  NA     0.6  NA  
3 2020-12-06  NA    NA     0.7
> Mary
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  date       Peter   Ben  Mary
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-03-30   0.2  NA    NA  
2 2020-10-14  NA     0.1  NA  
3 2020-12-06  NA    NA     0.9
```

Comment: how can we pipe that. like for `df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("var")) %>%
  group_split(name) %>%
  setNames(unique(df$Name)) %>%
  map(. %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = Name)) %>%
  map(. %>%  select(-name)) %>%....`

Comment: @TarJae you meant `mylistdf %>% massign(names(.), ., .GlobalEnv)` ?

Comment: That is perfect. thanks master!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
list2env(mylistdf,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

but it is often recommended to keep your frames/tibbles in the original list.

Comment: Thanks @langtang. This obvious solution did not came in my mind!